# Removing the Object Moved HTML in the body on a Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple redirect in my code:

```
public ActionResult Redirect()
{
    return Redirect("http://url.com");
}
```

I noticed that the response includes the following html in the response body:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://url.com
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Date: Tue, 24 Jul 2012 18:53:52 GMT
Content-Length: 198

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="http://url.com">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Is there a way to remove the html from the response body? I would like the Content-Length to be zero by not having anything in the response body.

Comment: If you are using IIS 7 then you can use Using URL Rewrite Module 2.0, then you dont have to worry about the mvc action I believe

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option. It has to happen within the MVC action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by implementing your own `ActionResult` instead of using the built in `RedirectResult`, which will send that HTML.

However, you should not need to - the user should never see that markup, but it is provided for, mostly, legacy issues. Also be aware some browsers can be set to not follow redirects - not having the body there would then render the result pretty useless.

If you still want a Redirect without body, this result class would do it:

```
public sealed class RedirectResultNoBody : ActionResult
{
    private readonly string location;
    public RedirectResultNoBody(string location) 
    {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) 
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.StatusCode = 302;
        response.RedirectLocation = location;
        response.End();
    }
}
```

Which would then be used like this:

```
public ActionResult Redirect()
{
    return new RedirectResultNoBody("http://url.com");
}
```

Comment: I assume the RedirectResult uses HttpContext.Response under the hood. Is there anything in there that I need to know in order to get this done?

Comment: @Thomas, I expanded the answer. The code should be close to complete but I wrote it in hand without the compiler around, so you might need to tweak it a bit - but is does demonstrate the principle: Simply write what you need to the response in `ExecuteResult`, and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

If everything works as normal user will not be able to see this screen. This can be seen only if server is very busy or client machine is severely under-resourced.

Also if in case something failed on redirect, user can click on the page. So I would recommend not to change it.

If you insist to change it, I believe providing templates for error 302 should work the trick, which can be done in ASP.NET or IIS.

Comment: I totally understand but I still insist. When you say templates are you referring to the Error Pages in IIS or Web.Config?

Comment: Under MVC, the IIS templates for 302, etc, is not used.